# How to deploy Neural Machine Translation checkpoints on Azure as endpoints and microservice

Tags: azure, deployment, microservices, azure-machine-learning-service

I find it straightforward to deploy simple Machine Learning models on AzureML after training, as we can serialize the trained model into a single .pkl file, for example. However, for Neural Machine Translation models, especially when fine-tuning pre-trained models, we end up with up to eleven files. These files can be uploaded to Hugging Face for testing.

I have been attempting to deploy these checkpoints on Azure as endpoints but have been unsuccessful, despite reading and following the Azure documentation. If anyone knows of a clear tutorial or has experience deploying such models on Azure, I would greatly appreciate the guidance. Additionally, I would love to know how to deploy these models as microservices on Azure. Thank you.

I have read Microsoft's documentation on deployment, but I couldn't find specific information on deploying checkpoints for Neural Machine Translation models.

[Here are files from the chekpoints after training and finetuning NMT models](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XxZvQ.png)

Comment: What is the approach you tried? and what error you facing? Please add more details on environment where you fine-tuning the models.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @JayashankarGS I'm using Azure Machine Learning Studio. Since the checkpoints consist of eleven files, I've serialized them into scoring files and uploaded them to the model. Then, I go to the endpoint and deploy the model. I have a scoring file, which is the test.py file I use to load the checkpoints and test them. However, the deployment always fails, and I'm new to Azure. Thank you.

Comment: @Friedrich I am trying to deploy a Neural Machine Translation (NMT) model on Azure Machine Learning Studio that has multiple files in his checkpoint.  Could you provide step-by-step guidance or point me to a tutorial that explains this process of deploying NMT models?

Comment: @SakayoToadoumSariVII What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Provide the document you referred. Screenshot of files you are getting at checkpoint.

Comment: It shows failed to deployed that's all

Comment: What are the file you have in check point. `model.pkl`, `score.py` and dependenices are there.

Comment: @JayashankarGS for nmt models you have 11 files (artifacts,) all of them together that work as language model. If I need a model.pkl, how should I serialize these files? There is a score.py to load the model and test it

Comment: @JayashankarGS I have added screenshoot for the checkpoints' files to the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, foundation models of this kind can be deployed from the `Hugging Face` registry in Azure ML.

[image]

So, you register your model with Hugging Face and try deploying it in Azure ML.

[image]

There is a component in the Azure ML registry where you can convert these models to `Mlflow`. Check this [notebook](https://github.com/Azure/azureml-examples/blob/main/sdk/python/foundation-models/system/import/import_model_into_registry.ipynb) for more information.

After converting, you can deploy it to an endpoint.

But before all of this, you need to register a new model in Hugging Face with these files.

Comment: The Azure ML from HuggingFace is not yet working at my end when I select this. Also it for a company so they models on huggingface to be private. Thanks for your help

Comment: I have already put it on huggingface and it's working, it is just private repo